# Roots of monic complex polynomial lie on a circle of radius $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

A problem in my topology course asks to show that there exists a large enough $R$ such that $f(x)=z_n x^n + \dots + z_0$ has no roots on $ \mid z \mid =R$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem or where to begin looking, when I search online I am just directed to polynomials whose roots lie on the unit circle.

Also, I have not seen much complex analysis so hopefully it will not play a major role.

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: If $f(a) = 0$, then $|z_n a^n| \leq |z_{n-1} a^{n-1}| + \cdots + |z_1 a| + |z_0|$ by the triangle inequality.

Comment: That hint may have been for a more general problem (I am not completely sure about the notation).  You can also ask how many roots a polynomial can have, total.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem does not read "has no roots on $|z| > R$"? (Slade's hint above can be used to prove this) Otherwise its trivial: fix any $R_0$ and consider the $n+1$ circles $|z|=R_0$,$|z|=2R_0$, $|z|=3R_0$, $\ldots$ $|z|=(n+1)R_0$. By the pigeonhole principle there exist at least one circle where $f$ does not have a zero.

Comment: @Winther: that's using the fact that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ distinct roots. Using that, the problem itself is rather trivial as well.

Comment: @tomasz The proof that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots is just as simple: assume it has more than $n$ roots and do polynomial division over the first $n$ roots. That being said, the first hint is definately the best way to go here.